# org.hibernate.MappingException: An AnnotationConfiguration instance is required

Tags: java, hibernate, maven, tomcat

В общем получаю данную ошибку при попытке получить данные из БД mySql в сервлете.

```
@WebServlet(name = "PatientServlet", urlPatterns = "/patient")
 public class PatientServlet extends HttpServlet {

protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

}

protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

    Session session = HibernateUtill.getSessionFactory().openSession();
    PatientDAOImpl patientDAO = new PatientDAOImpl();
    patientDAO.setSession(session);

    try {
        request.setAttribute("patients", patientDAO.findAll());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    request.getRequestDispatcher("WEB-INF/patient.jsp").forward(request, response);
}
```

}

Использую maven, все зависимости удовлетворены. Если я пытаюсь подключиться к БД из обычного класса, не сервлета, и просто вывожу какие-то данные из БД в консоль, все работает.

```
org.hibernate.MappingException: An AnnotationConfiguration instance is required to use <mapping class="com.likhanov.model.dao.entities.Patient"/>
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.parseMappingElement(Configuration.java:1597)
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.parseSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1552)
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.doConfigure(Configuration.java:1531)
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.doConfigure(Configuration.java:1505)
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.configure(Configuration.java:1425)
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.configure(Configuration.java:1411)
at com.likhanov.model.HibernateUtill.<clinit>(HibernateUtill.java:11)
at com.likhanov.controllers.PatientServlet.doGet(PatientServlet.java:25)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:624)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:218)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:505)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:169)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:958)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:452)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1087)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:637)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:318)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [PatientServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Servlet execution threw an exception] with root cause
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
at com.likhanov.model.HibernateUtill.<clinit>(HibernateUtill.java:15)
at com.likhanov.controllers.PatientServlet.doGet(PatientServlet.java:25)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:624)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:218)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:505)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:169)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:958)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:452)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1087)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:637)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:318)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Полный код в [репозиторие](https://github.com/deLikh/Registry).

Ошибка, кстати, указывает на класс HibernateUtill. Я подозреваю, что tomcat не видит файл hibernate.cfg.xml.

В war файл упаковал все доступные либы, что подтащил maven. Понимаю, что возможно это излишне, так как сама idea ничего об этом не предупреждала (fix не загорался), но думал хоть так заработает. Еще закинул конфиг. файл от hibernate.

Просто запускаю и перехожу по нужному адресу. По идее сервлет, отвечающий за этот адрес, должен вытянуть из бд нужные данные, но падает, и указывает на HibernateUtill. Извиняюсь, если что, только начал работать с вебом.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Посмотрите на строку 14 [HibernateUtill](https://github.com/deLikh/Registry/blob/master/src/main/java/com/likhanov/model/HibernateUtill.java). Код глотает все исключения и выводит их в лог. Т.о. `ExceptionInInitializerError` мало о чем говорит. Приведите записи по предыдущим исключениям.

Comment: Вывел стек трейс по ошибке. Лог ошибок изменен. Проблема конкретно в интеграции tomcat и hibernate. Без tomcat все работает.

Comment: [вот решение](https://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/hibernate-error-an-annotationconfiguration-instance-is-required-to-use/)

Comment: и еще расскажите как собираете и деплоете на сервер.

Comment: Я бы вставил еще картинок, но больше нельзя.

Comment: покажите facets

Comment: Поменял рисунок.

Comment: @DenisL29 а теперь покажите artefacts -> вкладка output layout

Comment: Готово, как и писал, добавил все что было справа.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблему решил. Сменил configuration() на  AnnotationsConfiguration(), а так же добавил более старую зависимость hibernate core.